# How to solve the alignment problem of the columns in a text file after copy and paste?

Tags: shell, text-processing, awk, command-line, columns

I copied column 7,8 and 9 from file 1 into columns 7,8 and 9 in file 2 producing a new file 3. the produced file (file 3) is not aligned as the original files, How can I edit it to preserve the alignment ?

I used the command:

```
awk '(getline line < "file 1") > -1 {split(line,a); $7 = a[7]; $8 = a[8]; $9= a[9]} 1' file 2 > file 3
```

file 1:

```
GRM in vacuum

192700

1GRM     C1    1  17.188   0.311  13.994 -0.5971  0.0204 -0.0724
1GRM     C2    2   0.094   0.383   0.005  0.4831 -0.8709 -0.2204
1GRM     C3    3   0.091   0.524   0.008 -0.7098  0.3449 -0.3952
```

file 2:

```
GRM in vacuum

192760

1GRM     C1    1   0.061   0.071  14.000 
1GRM     C2    2   0.184   0.142  14.000
1GRM     C3    3   0.184   0.284   0.000
```

file 3 (The output):

```
GRM in vacuum

192760

1GRM C1 1 0.061 0.071 14.000 -0.5971 0.0204 -0.0724
1GRM C2 2 0.184 0.142 14.000 0.4831 -0.8709 -0.2204
1GRM C3 3 0.184 0.284 0.000 -0.7098 0.3449 -0.3952
```

To solve the alignment problem I used:

```
    awk 'BEGIN{fmt="%10s%9s%7d%8.3f%8.3f%8.3f%8.4f%8.4f%8.4f"} (getline line < "file 1") > -1 {n = split(line,a)} n > 6 {$0 = sprintf(fmt,$1,$2,$3,$4,$5,$6,a[7],a[8],a[9])} 1' "file 2" > file 3
```

but still I have 2 problems.

The first problem is the alignment of the columns in the output file is not like the original files (file 1 and file 2).

The second problem happens at line 10002, column 2 and 3 combine together which lead to disappearing a complete column in the output file starting from line 10002 to the end, below are the 3 files at line 10002:

file 1:

```
2500GRM     C3 9999  15.716   8.242   0.002  0.2372 -0.2989 -0.0758   # line 10001
2500GRM     C410000  15.592   8.311   0.003  0.2603 -0.2492 -0.2394   # line 10002
2501GRM     C110001  15.591   8.453   0.006  0.0887 -0.2458 -0.7014   # line 10003
2501GRM     C210002  15.714   8.524   0.007 -0.0788  0.0598 -0.9619   # line 10004
```

file 2:

```
2500GRM     C3 9999  15.433   8.378   0.000   # line 10001
2500GRM     C410000  15.310   8.449   0.000   # line 10002
2501GRM     C110001  15.310   8.591   0.000   # line 10003
2501GRM     C210002  15.433   8.662   0.000   # line 10004
```

file 3:

```
2500GRM C3 9999 15.433 8.378 0.000 0.2372 -0.2989 -0.0758   # line 10001
2500GRM C410000 15.310 8.449 0.000  -0.2492 -0.2394         # line 10002
2501GRM C110001 15.310 8.591 0.000  -0.2458 -0.7014         # line 10003
2501GRM C210002 15.433 8.662 0.000  0.0598 -0.9619          # line 10004
```

I have attached all the files in the below link:

https://drive.google.com/drive/folders/13diMVxlp-T9BXE_jnm_LL1jUPbz8eren

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem is that you have either 8 or 9 data fields in `file1` and 5 or 6 in `file2`. Either `C3 9999` 
is one badly formatted field or `C410000` should be two fields `C4` and `10000`.

To adjust the formatting depending on the number of fields you can

- use two format strings and switch between them
- save the number of array elements `n` when you split the line and take the last 
  three values `a[n-2]`, `a[n-1]`, `a[n]`

```
awk '
  BEGIN{
    fmt1="%8s %6s%5s %7.3f %7.3f %7.3f %7.4f %7.4f %7.4f" ORS
    fmt2="%8s %11s %7.3f %7.3f %7.3f %7.4f %7.4f %7.4f" ORS
  }
  (getline line < "file 1") > -1{
    n=split(line, a)
  }
  NF<=3{ print; next }                                                     # print original line 
  NF==6{ printf fmt1, $1, $2, $3, $4, $5, $6, a[n-2], a[n-1], a[n]; next } # 6 + 3 fields
  { printf fmt2, $1, $2, $3, $4, $5, a[n-2], a[n-1], a[n] }                # 5 + 3 fields
' "file 2" > "file 3"
```

Output:

```
 ...
 2500GRM     C3 9999  15.433   8.378   0.000  0.2372 -0.2989 -0.0758
 2500GRM     C410000  15.310   8.449   0.000  0.2603 -0.2492 -0.2394
 2501GRM     C110001  15.310   8.591   0.000  0.0887 -0.2458 -0.7014
 2501GRM     C210002  15.433   8.662   0.000 -0.0788  0.0598 -0.9619
 ...
```